# Manually adding a date (month) column to a query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, union

So essentially I have a table that looks like this:

```
SalesPerson    Target 
John           50000.00
Bill           75000.00
Jake           40000.00
```

I want to add a new column that will make my query look like this:

```
SalesPerson    Target      Month
John           50000.00    01/01/14
Bill           75000.00    01/01/14
Jake           40000.00    01/01/14 
John           50000.00    02/01/14
Bill           75000.00    02/01/14
Jake           40000.00    02/01/14
```

And so on....  Obviously the target is a monthly value. The purpose is to be used in a pivot chart in Tableau.

The month field needs to be datetime which should be easy.  The only thing coming to mind is to manually do something like:

```
Convert(datetime, '2014-01-01 00:00:000') as 'MONTH'
```

and then do that 11 more times and use UNION all each time.  This just seems like a lot of text and time.  I'm hoping there is a much easier way.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a somehow bizarre scenario, why would you need to repeat every value of your table for every month?. That said, this is one way to do it:

```
SELECT  A.*,
        DATEADD(MONTH,B.number,'20140101') AS [Month]
FROM YourTable A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 11) B
```

Do be aware that this is multiplying the number of rows of your table by 12.

Comment: Yeah the way the DB was setup is horrible.  These monthly values are entered once in a table just like you see.  I need to aggregate them in a chart. Trying your answer and will report back... oh but to answer your question, I can't add this to my pivot table without a date field.

Comment: This did it! way faster than my idea and no way I would have came up with this on my own.  Now I'm going to study this and try to understand why it works.